# A functional ecuation using divizors

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, mobius-inversion

It’s a functional equation. We have a function f defined on pozitive integers (greater than 0) with values on real numbers. Also,[image] for any pozitive (and non zero) integer n. It asks to find function f.

In their solution, they found f(1)=1 and by substituting n with p^n where p is a pozitive prime number, they also found f(p^n)=p^n - p^(n-1) for any prime p and for any pozitive integer n>0. Next they said they prove by induction by s=mn that f(mn)=f(m)f(n) for any relatively prime positive integers m and n. So proof by induction by s=mn. For s=1 it is clear that it’s true. Suppose the statement is true for any s<=t where t>=1 and prove the statement for s+1. So, let m,n relatively prime positive integers such that mn=t+1. We have [image]
But I didn’t understand anything starting from mn=..... . Could you please help me understand what they did here? I don’t know sigma sum symbol well.. so could you please explain step by step what they did? Thank you! Also if it helps, the result is f(n)= Euler’s totient function of n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The divisors $d$ of $nm$ are of the form $d_1 d_2$ with $d_1\mid m$ and $d_2\mid n$. Thus
$$mn=\sum_{d\mid nm} f(d)=\sum_{d_1\mid n, d_2\mid m} f(d_1 d_2)=
\sum_{d_1\mid n} \sum_{ d_2\mid m} f(d_1 d_2)=\\\sum_{d_1\mid n, d_1\not=n} \sum_{ d_2\mid m} f(d_1 d_2)+\sum_{ d_2\mid m} f(n d_2)=\sum_{d_1\mid n, d_1\not=n} \sum_{ d_2\mid m} f(d_1 d_2)+\sum_{ d_2\mid m, d_2\not=m} f(n d_2)+f(nm).$$ By induction hypotheses (should be $f(uv)=f(u)f(v)$ for all coprime $u,v$ with $uv<nm$) this simplifies to
$$nm=\sum_{d_1\mid n, d_1\not=n} \sum_{ d_2\mid m} f(d_1)f(d_2)+\sum_{ d_2\mid m, d_2\not=m} f(n)f( d_2)+f(nm)=\\
\sum_{d_1\mid n, d_1\not=n}  f(d_1)\sum_{ d_2\mid m}f(d_2)+f(n)\sum_{ d_2\mid m, d_2\not=m} f( d_2)+f(nm)=
\\
\left(\sum_{d_1\mid n}  f(d_1)-f(n)\right)\sum_{ d_2\mid m}f(d_2)+f(n)\left(\sum_{ d_2\mid m} f( d_2)-f(m)\right)+f(nm)=\\
(n-f(n))m+f(n)(m-f(m))+f(nm)=nm-f(n)f(m)+f(mn),
$$
the desired result.